# SVM: Are all the support vectors necessarily used to construct the weights

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I know what exactly the SVM is and very clear about the principles and algorithms. But I'm curious about are all support vectors necessarily used in constructing weights $w$.

> Let $w^Tx_i + b$ denote SVM model. Based on KKT dual complementarity condition,
>
> $\alpha_i[y_i(w^Tx_i+b)-1]=0, i=1,\cdots,N,$
>
> where $w$ and $b$ are weights and bias, $\alpha_i$ is Lagrange multiplier.

we know that if $\alpha_i \not=0$, then $y_i(w^Tx_i+b)-1=0$. And such a $x_i$ is called support vector. Sequentially, the estimation of weights $w = \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_{(i)}y_{(i)}x_{(i)}$ where $x_{(i)}s$ are the support vectors.

What I'm confused about is:

> Is it possible that some $\alpha_0=0$ and $y_0(w^Tx_0+b)-1=0$ hold simultaneously so that such a $x_i$ is a support vector itself, but is not used in constructing weights $w$, since $\alpha_0=0$.

Thanks for any ideas. :)